# Database design layout

Tags: mysql

I’m creating a database chat program in java to inorder to practice MySQL.

I’ve created 3 tables so far:

1. A chat log to record the names and passwords of current chat sessions
2. A user log to record their usernames, passwords and current chat
3. A bug log to allow for automatic error reporting and content issues

But I’m wondering what would be the best and most efficient way of storing the chat messages. Should I create a new table for each chat (using the name from the chat log table to ID it) or have one big table which stores all the messages for all the chats and reference the chat name as a foreign key.

Comment: Second option is preferred, but for foreign key you should use chat ID instead of chat name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's considere only tables `ChatLog` and `UserLog` so far.

**ChatLog**

```
chatid | chatname | chatpassword
-------+----------+-------------
1      | foo      | bar
2      | lol      | xD
```

**UserLog**

```
userid | username   | userpassword
-------+------------+-------------
1      | chatbot    | skynet
2      | john       | doe
3      | chucknixon | thegreatone
```

For messages logs, my approach would be the last one you wrote, having one big table with foreign keys.

**MessageLog**

```
messageid | userid | chatid | messagecontent
----------+--------+--------+---------------
1         | 1      | 1      | john has joined the chat
2         | 1      | 1      | chucknixon has joined the chat
3         | 2      | 1      | hello chuck
4         | 1      | 2      | john has joined the chat
5         | 3      | 1      | Hi john how are you ?
```

The relational logic and structure structures will then looks like this :

-a unique *user* can write **0 or n** *messages*

-a unique *message* can be wrote by **1 and only** 1 *user*

-a unique *chat room* can contain **0 or n** *messages*

-a unique *message* can be contained in **1 and only 1** *chat room*

> [UserLog] 0,n -> (to write) <- 1,1 [MessageLog] 1,1 -> (to contain) <- 0,n [ChatLog]